# Using RhinoMocks, how do you mock or stub a concrete class without an empty constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, tdd, rhino-mocks

Mocking a concrete class with Rhino Mocks seems to work pretty easy when you have an empty constructor on a class:

```
public class MyClass{
     public MyClass() {}
}
```

But if I add a constructor that takes parameters and remove the one that doesn't take parameters:

```
public class MyClass{
     public MyClass(MyOtherClass instance) {}
}
```

I tend to get an exception:

> System.MissingMethodException : Can't
>   find a constructor with matching
>   arguments

I've tried putting in nulls in my call to Mock or Stub, but it doesn't work.

Can I create mocks and stubs of concrete classes that lack parameter-less constructors?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yep. Just pass in the parameters in your `StrictMock()` call:

```
// New FruitBasket that can hold 50 fruits.
MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
FruitBasket basket = mocks.StrictMock<FruitBasket>(50);
```

Comment: and compile-time safety goes out the window

Answer (score 3):

If you Mock a concrete class without an empty/default constructor, then Rhino Mocks is going to have to use whatever other constructors are available.  Rhino is going to need you to supply the parameters for any non-empty constructors since it won't have any clue how to build them otherwise.

My mistake is that I was attempting to pass nulls to the `CreateMock` or `GenerateMock` call, as soon as I generated a a non-null parameter for the constructor, the calls to create the mock or stub began working.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass them in after your `DynamicMock<T>` statement, which takes a parameter array as an argument.  Unfortunately there's no type checking on it, but it will call the appropriate constructor if you match up your arguments to the signature.

For example:

```
var myMock = MockRepository.DynamicMock<MyClassWithVirtuals>(int x, myObj y);
```